# Can Azure data centers be considered complaint with Uptime Institute's Tier 3 Classification requirements?

Tags: azure, datacenter

[Uptime Institute](https://uptimeinstitute.com/tier-certification) certifies data center designs, facilities, and operations to the Tier Classification System (I-IV) and Operational Sustainability criteria. Can Azure data centers be considered complaint with [Uptime Institute's Tier 3 Classification requirements](https://journal.uptimeinstitute.com/explaining-uptime-institutes-tier-classification-system/)?

Comment: Do you want an anecdotal answer or an authoritative answer? If authoritative, direct your question to Microsoft itself.

Comment: Either will work at this point!

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft's document called [Standard Response to Request for Information Microsoft Azure Security, Privacy, and Compliance](https://azure.microsoft.com/mediahandler/files/resourcefiles/azure-standard-response-to-rfi-on-security-privacy-and-compliance/Azure%20-%20Standard%20Response%20for%20Request%20for%20Information%20-%20Compliance%20Privacy%20and%20Security.pdf), page 49 onwards, Microsoft intentionally does not have an Uptime Institute Tier certification:

> While Microsoft supports the spirit of the Uptime Institute’s Availability classifications, which are prescriptive-based for easy adoption by the industry as a whole, we have chosen to use a more performance-based approach that uses science to match the SLAs to the customer need. Microsoft’s data centers are engineered to provide 99.999% availability to meet our customer’s SLAs and service needs.
>
> [...]
>
> As a result, Microsoft’s data centers are evolving at a more rapid pace than many facilities in the industry and thus do not follow the guidelines outlined by Uptime Institute’s tier classifications. Therefore, we do not pursue Uptime certification of our facilities.

Basically, they (sort of) promise 99.999 % uptime for their data centers and claim that the Uptime Institute standards do not evolve quick enough to keep up with their best practices. Looking at the availability figure though, they promise that their data centers offer the same availability (or better) as a Tier 4 data center (which, according to https://phoenixnap.com/blog/data-center-tiers-classification, would require at least 99.995% of uptime).

Comment: Similar language is found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/compliance/assurance/assurance-datacenter-architecture-infrastructure#availability, although the Uptime Institute is not mentioned explicitly there